# show actions in dropdown on ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, angular9

I have added custom actions like this:
settings = { actions: { delete: true, add: false, edit: false, custom: [ { name: 'edit', title: 'Edit' }, { name: 'duplicate', title: 'duplicate' }, ] } }

And I get this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/novEC.png)

but I want to show actions like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1E8K.png)

Comment: please anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Angular Material Menu module.
You can find it here : https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview